# Xamarin.forms webservice to azure database

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I am a newbie in Xamarin and I am looking for a way to send information  to the azure database with Xamarin.forms, I am using webservice.

What I have done:

1-I have already created my azure database online

2-I have make the code to send information

Problem:

1-I do not know what I have to put in client.PostAsync to sending my information (email ,password, confirmpassword)

Here is the code :

```
public class ApiServices
    {
        public async Task <bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var model = new RegisterBindingModel
            {
                Email=email,
                Password=password,
                ConfirmPassword= confirmPassword

            };

            // to send my information
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


              // what do I need to put in PostAsync?
            var response= await client.PostAsync("",content);


            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance .  if you have better solution and somme information to know , I will take it.

Comment: do you have a webservice for your db?

Comment: @Jason I do not know about it. Ionly have ADO.net /JDBC and ODBC

Comment: webservices have been a common tool in programming for at least 10 years now.  You should really be familiar with them: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: I know a little bit about it , but I cannot see how I can interact with azure database

Comment: there must be a thousand articles/samples/blogs about using webservices with Azure databases.

Comment: yes I am just looking for a simple one , if some have already done it

Answer (score 0):

First argument of PostAsync must be Uri of Service, e.g. `http://mywebservice.com/api/user`

Comment: your link have nothing

Comment: @mkis it's not a link. This is an example

Comment: I see , so do you how I can send my information to database , the same way with azure